# Use cat to sort multiple fastq files in a directory

Tags: bash, fastq

I have the following to sort my fastq by their sequence identifiers:

```
zcat 001_T1_1.fastq.gz | paste - - - - | sort -k1,1 -t " " | tr "\t" "\n" | gzip -c > 001_T1_1_sorted.fastq.gz
zcat 001_T1_2.fastq.gz | paste - - - - | sort -k1,1 -t " " | tr "\t" "\n" | gzip -c > 001_T1_2_sorted.fastq.gz
```

It is a bit slow when i am trying it for one sample. Can we make it faster and run for all fastq.gz in a directory?
How can i make it with bash ?

Comment: This question is better suited on https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: You can try setting the sort buffer size larger, .e.g. `-S 4G`, and using multiple threads for sorting (e.g. `--parallel=8`). Also, if you have many cores you could additionally specify `--compress-prog=gzip`, which causes temporary files to be stored compressed, which might drastically increase IO throughput.

Comment: I have 64 cores. How can i make it run for all my fastq files in the directory ? with * or is it better to put it in a script in bash?

Comment: processing multiple files in parallel is certainly doable (eg, `parallel`, `xargs`, custom `while` loop, etc) but you'll need to watch out for bottlenecks in cpu, memory and/or  *disk*; you may also want to run some searches on options for sorting fastq files (as opposed to rolling your own code) as there may be some tools that are more efficient from a resource usage perspective

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be a bit faster as we remove two executables from the pipe-line:

```
zcat file_in.gz | 
awk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_str_asc"}
     {n=int((NR-1)/4); a[n] = a[n] $0 ORS }
     END { for(i in a) printf "%s",a[i] }' - | gzip -c - > file_out.gz
```

Comment: I have to make it for 800 files in a directory so maybe a bash script would be good idea ? on a script with snakemake ?

Comment: `awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=244699036) fatal: not enough arguments to satisfy format string
 `%s@A00711:290:HVJTFDMXX:2:1101:10004:15092 '1:N:0:TGATGTCC+AAGCGTTC
CTGAGCCAGCAGTGAGGGTTTAAAGTTGGACTTGATGACCACCTTGACCTCCAGTTTGGTGCGTCCCACTTCTCGCACTAGCGGGATCACCCGGAAGGGAAGGATGATGTCCTTGGTTGTGCGATACCTCATAAGCTCAAACTCTCCATCT
+
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
'
  ^ ran out for this one`

Comment: @user3683485 There was a missing comma. Should be fixed now. (btw, that are a lot of records)

Comment: yes that's why i am looking for a solution which is fast and apparently everything i tried until now doesn't work